# Background image does not want to load in css

Tags: html, css, django, flexbox, css-selectors

I am creating a website in Django. I downloaded a html homepage template design on the internet that I want to improve upon and use for my website. since its been designed it came with a CSS file. now when I try to make the improvements specifically add a background image in one of the elements. it refuses to do so. the other elements respond to the CSS style but the background image refuses too. since I'm using Django i had to set up the static files and 'collect static' which I did but when I set that those pics to my background image in my CSS it refuses. here is the html file & css.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Created by CodingLab |www.youtube.com/c/CodingLabYT-->
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> Home </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
  <!-- Boxicons CDN Link -->
  <link href= 
 'https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' 
  rel='stylesheet'>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
  scale=1.0">
</head>

<section class="home-section">
  <div class="main" >
    
  </div>
```

the class="main" is where I'm trying to add the background-image too.

CSS

```
.home-section .main{
  background-image: url('https://www.pexels.com/photo/singer- 
  singing-on-stage-beside-guitar-player-and-bass-player- 
  167636/');
  padding: auto;
  margin: auto;
  background-size: 50pc;
 }
@media (max-width: 700px) {
.sidebar li .tooltip{
display: none;
 }
 }
```

I've tried everything but it refuses to acquis. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your background-image url is invalid. You have to provide a valid link connected to an image, that link ports to a pexels webpage.

Comment: This link is not what I was using previously. I just tried it now and it failed as well but previously, since I have this pic in my static folder of my app I've been trying to use it but it refuses.

Comment: try to resize html, body and .home-section as well

Comment: its still not working I'm starting to suspect the template something wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Load Static or have non-empty div**

Without knowing what more code you have I can only guess that perhaps you forgot to load static files by including this on the top of your html file:

```
{% load static %}
```

Second, until the div is filled with something, it has no dimensions, so the image would occupy no space either.